# If statement - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I have this array that I have created full of values and basically I want to go thru an if statement to check for every value that is input into the array is of a certain condition. The condition is fine and I have all the values that I need but this if statement is taking all the values from the redsigma array rather than each one from the array. How do I put each value into the if statement rather than the whole array. Relatively new to c++. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7990272; i++)
{
 float redsigma[] = { img1->pixels[i].r + img2->pixels[i].r + img3->pixels[i].r + img4->pixels[i].r}

if (redsigma[0] > lbounds && redsigma[0] < upbounds)
{
                  do work blah blah blah
}
}
```

Comment: A + is not a , => you have one value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for-loop to iterate over the elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < the length of redsigma; ++i) {
    if(redsigma[i] meets conditions) {
    }
}
```

I recommend that you use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: @Russsu a vector is higher level than an array, and is therefore more memory safe. For example, accessing an array out of bounds results in a segfault, while accessing a vector out of bounds using the `at` function (but not the `[]` operator) results in an exception. Vectors also allow you to use iterators and the for-each syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Downvoters, could you please explain what was wrong with my answer? The OP wanted to know how to check each element of the array instead of the entire thing, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Oddly enough `redsigma` only contains one element, so using index 0 is correct. The OP has some other problem.